# Как получить id формы при клике на дочерний элемент с классом (id у формы уникально)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-form

При клике на кнопку с классом remove нужно получить id формы, в которой находится именно эта кнопка. Вот код с двумя формами (Две одинаковые формы с разными ID (генерируются с помощью PHP)):

[image: "Две одинаковые формы с разными ID (генерируются с помощью PHP)]

А скрипт у меня следующий

`$(".remove").on("click", function(){
        alert ($(this).parent().parent().attr("id"));
      });`

Comment: Прошу прощения, картинка с кодом не была добавлена

Comment: Да, он находится в `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`

Comment: Опишите текущее поведение. Варианты: не показывается `alert`, показаывается `alert` с неправильным текстом, браузер закрывается, компьютер выключается.

Comment: Не показывал alert

Comment: Всё заработало, была мелкая ошибка кода) Спасибо)

Comment: добавьте `console.log(".remove.click");` перед вызовом `alert` и посмотрите сообщения/ошибки в консоли браузера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что происходит в Вашем коде? Он соответствует показаной структуре DOM. Скрипт внутри `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`?

https://api.jquery.com/closest/

```
alert($(this).closest("form").attr("id"));
```

Comment: Начал собирать решение, а когда вернулся на страницу, то оно вот уже. Почти тоже самое, но в динамике: https://codepen.io/shugich/pen/LymRLW

Comment: Спасибо, ваш скрипт помог, кажется где-то ошибка внутри кода. Буду искать. На измененном, мной скрипте работает (Добавил несколько форм с разными id)